# Why are favicons not showing up on Google?

Tags: google-chrome, website, bookmarks, favicon

When I type in a URL or bookmark name on Google Chrome, sometimes the favicon for the website doesn't show up. Instead what shows up and it shows a white star instead. It's not a big problem, but sometimes I remember the website's favicon so I know what it is. Now, it just shows up as a star and I don't know why. Sometimes is shows the favicon even though it is from the same site, but sometimes even though the URL is from the same site, it doesn't show.

Is there any way to fix this?
Thanks.

Star showing up:
[image]

Comment: are you talking about a favicon? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon Browsers handle favicons specially, since they are displayed to the user even when the browser is offline or the user hasn't made a request for the domain during this session. so it caches them. I know the browser manufacturers are trying to improve that behavior now, because recently some companies have been using dynamic favicons to persistently track users, so you may be seeing a change for that reason. Additionally, sometimes they get lost in cache, or it may even be that the domain in question doesnt post a favicon.ico

Comment: @FrankThomas yes thank you, that's what I meant.